# error in displaying pdf in react-pdf

Tags: reactjs, npm

I am new new to react, I am trying to display a pdf file on browser. I am getting an error as **failed to load PDF**. I am trying to run the sample program given in https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-pdf.

**App.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf';  

class MyApp extends Component {
  state = {
    numPages: null,
    pageNumber: 1,
  }

  onDocumentLoad = ({ numPages }) => {
    this.setState({ numPages });
  }

  render() {
    const { pageNumber, numPages } = this.state;

    return (
      <div>
        <Document
          file="./1.pdf"
          onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoad}
        >
          <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
        </Document>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default MyApp;
```

**index.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import registerServiceWorker from './registerServiceWorker';

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
registerServiceWorker();
```

**Error screenshot**

[image]

Comment: You can not reference a file on your local filesystem in an app running in a browser. It does not have access to your filesystem at all. Otherwise it would be possible for an arbitrary website to access files on your computer. That's why `./somePath` can't work. Your local web server needs to serve that file under a certain path relative to your host address e.g. `/media/1.pdf` or just `1.pdf` depending on where the file is located on your server and how your web server is configured.

Comment: It's likely the document path: `file="./1.pdf"`. This looks like a server-side path. Try to use absolute or relative URL to your file and make sure the browser can download the file. Open Developer Tools, inspect the Network tab, and make sure that a request is being sent to download the file, and the file is being downloaded successfully.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You load the file using `file="./1.pdf"` I believe that might be the problem.

If you have a file structure like:

- src

  - App.js
  - components

    - ShowPdfComponent.js
    - 1.pdf
- public

  - bundle.js

Then you need to move the `1.pdf` to `public` folder like this:

- src

  - App.js
  - components

    - ShowPdfComponent.js
- public

  - bundle.js
  - 1.pdf

Because when your compiled javascript code is being executed from `public/bundle.js` and `bundle.js` does not know how to get to `src/components/1.pdf` in file system.

There might be also a difference between production/development environment if you are using `webpack` and `webpack-dev-server`.

Look at `react-pdf` example. It has flat file structure. That is the reason why it works.

[image]

Comment: what if the file property contains url from public pdf like http://www.africau.edu/images/default/sample.pdf?

I got the same error when using url like above.

Answer (score 13):

Question is old but hope this help someone. I faced this issue and found a solution here https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/321.

`import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf';`

Add this to your constructor.

```
constructor(props){
        super(props);
        pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
    }
```

Answer (score 7):

if you are using create-react-app then you need to import differently like

```
import { Document, Page } from 'react-pdf/dist/esm/entry.webpack'
```

because it uses webpack under the hood.

Comment: This worked for me. Normal import was working for other people. But, it wasn't working for me.  macOS 12.3.1 (21E258)

Answer (score 6):

To work with react-pdf with webpack use below snippet.

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
```

Answer (score 4):

Here is the minimum setup you need to be able to display your pdf in react TypeScript:

```js
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf'

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/legacy/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;

const YourComponentReact = ({url}: {url: string}) => {
  return (<Document file={url}>
             <Page pageNumber={1} />
          </Document>)
}
```

You can add a quick button if you want to be able to change pages
You only need to download react-pdf and @types/react-pdf if you use typescript.

Answer (score 2):

You can import the pdf file using `import samplePdf from './1.pdf'` and can use directly like `file={samplePdf}` in your Document tag.

Answer (score 2):

adding pdfjs to import and using it like this hellped

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from 'react-pdf'

pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//unpkg.com/pdfjs-dist@${pdfjs.version}/legacy/build/pdf.worker.min.js`;
```

in the same file i need to show my pdf