# loading pdf file in react application

Tags: javascript, reactjs, pdf, react-pdf

I'm trying to show a pdf file with `react-pdf` package that is installed using `npm`

```
import { Document, Page, pdfjs } from "react-pdf";
import { useState } from "react";
import React from "react";

function PDFLayout(props){
  pdfjs.GlobalWorkerOptions.workerSrc = `//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/pdf.js/${pdfjs.version}/pdf.worker.js`;
  const [numPages, setNumPages] = useState(null);
  const [pageNumber, setPageNumber] = useState(1);

function onDocumentLoadSuccess({ numPages }) {
    setNumPages(numPages);
  }

  return (
    <div>
   // the file address is temporary and just for test 
    <Document  file="https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf" onLoadSuccess={onDocumentLoadSuccess}>
      <Page pageNumber={pageNumber} />
    </Document>
    <p>
      Page {pageNumber} of {numPages}
    </p>
  </div>

  );
}
export default PDFLayout;
```

and when i route to this react file i get this error:

> Failed to load pdf file

i checked other Question in SO and GH like :

- [ReactJS react-pdf error "Failed to load PDF file." on some attempts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72465876/reactjs-react-pdf-error-failed-to-load-pdf-file-on-some-attempts)
- [error in displaying pdf in react-pdf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48589169/error-in-displaying-pdf-in-react-pdf)
- https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/321

but the answers didn't work for me. so  I'm really appreciative of all the help you will give to me.

Comment: i have to handle it with react-pdf package. not any object or iframe or etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

instead of using a package you can embbed a pdf using the following code

```
<div class="embed-responsive" style={{ height: "100vh" }}>
        <embed
          src="https://www.orimi.com/pdf-test.pdf"
          type="application/pdf"
          width="100%"
          height="100%"
        />
</div>
```

It will open the browser's pdf viewer directly into your div

Comment: embed tag doesn't show up for me! but i can use <iframe> for it but it's not customizable enough.
so i have to build it with react-pdf

Comment: This has been a life saver for me as I was using all sorts of libraries like pdfjs-dist and react-pdf but this has been the most simplist and effective answer. Thanks again.

Comment: @AbdurRahman I'm glad that you appreciate the solution .

Answer (score 1):

It's also possible to use the HTML tag, `<object>`:

```
<object data="your/pdf/link" width={yourWidth} height={yourHeight} type="application/pdf" ></object>
```

Comment: in my case, I had to use the react-pdf package, but this is another solution to handle it

Answer (score 0):

This is because due to the CORS policy, let look the image below.[image]

So, this time you need to add a header to your server, to allow CORS policy.

Comment: i checked it. i'm not getting CORS Error!